# using stacktrace to get function caller file in node gives me wrong file path

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-trace

SO, I have 2 files, `a.js` and `b.js`

in `a.js`, i have a `test();` function that I'm calling from `b.js`

I also have the following code to help me find in what line of `b.js` is calling the function, and that works fine. But I also want to be getting the filename, and the code below gives me `a.js` instead of `b.js`.. any pointers?

```js
Object.defineProperty(global, "__stack", {
    get() {
        const orig = Error.prepareStackTrace;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = function(_, stack) {
            return stack;
        };
        const err = new Error;
        Error.captureStackTrace(err, arguments.callee);
        const stack = err.stack;
        Error.prepareStackTrace = orig;
        return stack;
    },
});

Object.defineProperty(global, "__line", {
    get() {
        return __stack[1].getLineNumber();
    },
});

Object.defineProperty(global, "__filename", {
    get() {
        return __stack[1].getFileName();
    },
});
```

Comment: I've looked for this in SO already, and everyone seems to be using `getFileName();` just like I am, so I must be doing something wrong but I'm not sure what...

Answer (score 0):

OK So, I'm not sure why but the

```js
Object.defineProperty(global, "__filename", {
    get() {
        return __stack[1].getFileName();
    },
});
```

part of the code provided wasn't working like expected. Idk what it was doing, all I know is I tried the following and it's working fine.

```js
Object.defineProperty(global, "__callerInfo", {
    get() {
        return [__stack[1].getLineNumber(), __stack[1].getFileName()];
    },
});
```

I'm just saving the line number in one constant and the file name in a different one